# Remove Links from 'My Account' side navigation

Tags: magento2, xml, customer-account

I am trying to remove some links from the 'My Account' section of `Magento 2.2.5`.

the links i want to remove are

- My Downloadable Products
- Stored Payment Methods
- Billing Agreements
- My Subscription Profiles
- My Saved Card Identifiers

after some research, i need to do this in `customer_account.xml`

and the code i am trying to use is

```
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>
```

However when i use these, it only displays the top 3 existing navigation links and i cant find the remove statements for the other mentioned links

Comment: These
 My Subscription Profiles
My Saved Card Identifiers
are not default link 
Can you please tell me where you add this?

Comment: im not sure what you mean?

Comment: i have updated my comment please check

Comment: They came with our magento installation from GitHub

Comment: Can you please share screenshot where you talking about?